# Error while running Jenkins in Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a docker with `jenkins` in it as below command:

> docker run --rm -p 2222:2222 -p 9080:9080 -p 8081:8081 -p 9418:9418
>   -tivjenkinsci/workflow-demo

I continuously get below errors

> INFO: Failed mkdirs of /var/jenkins_home/caches
>
> [7412] Connection from 127.0.0.1:57701 
>  
>   [7412] Extended attributes (16 bytes) exist 
>   [7412] Request upload-pack for '/repo'
>  
>   [4140] [7412] Disconnected
>  
>   [7415] Connection from 127.0.0.1:39829
>  
>   [7415] Extended attributes (16 bytes) exist 
>  
>   [7415] Request upload-pack for '/repo'
>  
>   [4140] [7415] Disconnected

I am following:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-aggregator-plugin/blob/master/demo/README.md

My configuration:

1. OS : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
2. user : jenkins
3. Checked inside the docker : directory /var/jenkins_home/caches was
   getting created as jenkins user, having another directory:
   git-f20b64796d6e86ec7654f683c3eea522
4. EVERYTHING IS DEFAULT

Comment: What OS are you using? Failed mkdirs of /var/jenkins_home/caches suggests a permissions issue. What user are you running jenkins as and does it have the necessary permissions?

Comment: I am using Centos7 (CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)) When I login to docker container : I see that directory is created. user is jenkins. Everything is default, I have not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

So if I google that error, I find a page: https://recordnotfound.com/git-plugin-jenkinsci-31194/issues (I know, not the project you're looking at but maybe same or similar issue) and that page if you just do a text search for that error, you'll see a line:

fix logging "Failed mkdirs of /var/jenkins_home/caches" when the directory already exists

it indicates that this is an open issue and that it was logged 11 days ago albeit for a different repo. if you delete the folder does it fix the issue? Maybe monitor that bug report for a fix or log an issue against the workflow-aggregator-plugin.

Comment: deleting the folder insider docker does not help. The error appears back.